# Rxjava observeOn and subscribeOn in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

**observeOn**:
This method simply changes the thread of all operators further downstream
(https://medium.com/upday-devs/rxjava-subscribeon-vs-observeon-9af518ded53a)

When calling API, I want to run the communicating with a server on IO thread and want to handle the result on mainThread.

I see the below code in many tutorials and no doubt it is correct. 
but my understanding is opposite so I'd like to know what I'm misunderstanding.

```
requestInterface.callApi()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe())
```

**observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())**

: observeOn changes the thread of all operators further downstream, but in the example, the actual calling API function is upper than observeOn?

**.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())**

: Weird part, it needs to be subscribed on main-thread, but subscribe on IO thread?

Please advise me What I'm misunderstanding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basic, we will have

```
Observable.subscribe(Observer);// => Observer observe Observable and Observable subscribe Observer
```

Example

```
requestInterface.callApi().subscribe(new Observer...); // requestInterface.callApi() <=> Observable
```

From the http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html

**SubscribeOn**

> - SubscribeOn operator designates which thread the **Observable** will begin operating on, no matter at what point in the chain of operators that operator is called

**ObserveOn** (affect 2 things)

> - It instructs the **Observable** to send notifications to **Observers** on a specified Scheduler.
> - ObserveOn affects the thread that the **Observable** will use below where that operator appears

#### Example

```
registerUserReturnedObserverble()  // run on worker thread because subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) (line 5)
.andThen(loginReturnObserverble()) // run on worker thread because subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) (line 5)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.andThen(getUserDataReturnObserverble()) // run on main thread because .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) is above this operator (line 3)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.subscribe(new Observer<Void>{
    // run on main thread because observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

- **subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())**: This tell the Observable to run the task on a background thread
- **observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())**: This tells the Observer to receive the data on android UI thread so that you can take any UI related actions.

Answer (score 1):

The following case specify all the different cases that can arise while using observeOn() and/Or subscribeOn().

1. `subscribeOn` affects **upstream** operators (operators above the subscribeOn)
2. `observeOn` affects **downstream** operators (operators below the observeOn)
3. If you don’t specify threading in RxJava (if you don’t specify `subscribeOn`, `observeOn` or both), the data will be emitted and processed by the current scheduler/thread (usually the main thread). For instance, all operators in the chain below will be processed by the current thread( Main thread in case of Android).

> ```
> Observable
> .just("big", "bigger", "biggest")    
> .map(String::length)    
> .filter { it > 6 }    
> .subscribe { length -> println("item length $length") }
> ```

4. If only subscribeOn is specified, all operators will be be executed on that thread

> ```
> Observable
> .just("big", "bigger", "biggest") 
> .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())    
> .map(String::length)    
> .filter { it > 6 }    
> .subscribe { length -> println("item length $length") }
> ```

Data emission just , the map and filter operator will be executed on the io scheduler as directed by the upstream operator `subscribeOn`.

5. If only `observeOn` is specified, all operators will be executed on the current thread and only operators below the `observeOn` will be switched to thread specified by the `observeOn`

> ```
> Observable
> .just("big", "bigger", "biggest")   
> .map(String::length)
> .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())     
> .filter { it > 6 }    
> .subscribe { length -> println("item length $length") }
> ```

Data emission just and the map will be executed on the currentThread scheduler .

filter will be executed on the computation scheduler as directed by the downstream operator `observeOn`.

6. if both `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` are specified, then all the operators below the `observeOn` will be switched to thread specified by the `observeOn` and rest all operators above `observeOn` are switched to thread specified by `subscribeOn` . This holds true in whatever order you specify `subscribeOn` and `observeOn`

> ```
> Observable
> .just("big", "bigger", "biggest")   
> .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) 
> .map(String::length)
> .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())     
> .filter { it > 6 }    
> .subscribe { length -> println("item length $length") }
> ```

Data emission just and the map operator will be executed on the io scheduler as directed by the upstream operator `subscribeOn`.

filter will be executed on the computation scheduler as directed by the downstream operator `observeOn`.

The thread usage would be the same even if subscribeOn would have been called after observeOn.

> ```
> Observable
> .just("big", "bigger", "biggest")  
> .map(String::length)
> .observeOn(Schedulers.computation()) 
> .filter { it > 6 }   
> .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) 
> .subscribe { length -> println("item length $length") }
> ```

Comment: subscribeOn affects upstream operators (operators above the subscribeOn) => I think subscribeOn affects all operators in the chain(if there is no obseveOn), no only the 'upstream' operators?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample:

```
      getCardsObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new rx.Observer<List<Card>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    listener.onError(e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Card> cards) {
                    listener.onSuccess(cards);
                }
            });
```

**subscribeOn -->** 
thread where the call will be executed similar to calling an asynctask

**observeOn -->** where the responses will be observed a process the UI thread

**subscribe -->** the observer callbacks